# ¿Cómo hacer varias consultas select con Laravel?

Tags: laravel

estoy usando laravel 6.0 y tengo este código que funciona a la perfección

```
$data = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
   ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as silver, cat_cliente'))->where('cat_cliente', '=','Silver')
   ->groupBy('cat_cliente')
   ->get();
    return view('Incidencias.index', compact('data'));
```

Quisiera hacer otro select, he intentado esto pero me da error:

```
$data = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
   ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as silver, cat_cliente'))->where('cat_cliente', '=','Silver')
   ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as gold, cat_cliente'))->where('cat_cliente', '=','Gold')
   ->groupBy('cat_cliente')
   ->get();
    return view('Incidencias.index', compact('data'));
```

Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Te recomiendo estudiar [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent) , las consultas son mas faciles de hacer y de enternder, y en tu problema intenta cambiando el segundo `select` por `where`.

Comment: hola, gracias por responder... Puedes ser un poco mas específico? he intendado cambiando el select por where y no ha funcionado

Comment: no se laravel, ni como estas haciendo las consultas.. pero si a la primera le sacas el where, deberia mostrar todas las categorias.. y si a la segunda le cambias el where para que sean solo silver y gold, y dejas un solo count, te deberia mostrar las dos cosas que queres. O sea, lo que estas mostrando suena a error de logica. Y cuando decis que algo no funciona (o tira error), siempre mostra que error tira o explica porque no funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considero que lo que buscas lo puedes resolver con un `CASE WHEN` de este modo:

```
$data = DB::table('incidencias')
           ->select('cat_client')
           ->selectRaw("COUNT(CASE WHEN cat_client = 'silver' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Silver")
           ->selectRaw("COUNT(CASE WHEN cat_cliente = 'gold' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Gold")
           ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
           ->groupBy('cat_cliente')
           ->get();
```

Donde:

- Hacemos un `COUNT` cuando `cat_client` sea igual a `silver` y le damos un alias de Silver
- Repetimos el paso anterior pero ahora para el caso de `gold`
- Generamos un `select` por separado para elegir a la columna `cat_client` que es la que ocupas para hacer tu agrupamiento
- Sustituye el uso de `DB::raw` por el método `selectRaw`
- De modo que al aplicar el uso del `CASE WHEN` vas a ponder establecer múltiples condiciones y cuando cada una se cumpla te genere una columna nueva con el valor deseado

**Referencias**

- [MySQL CASE WHEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)